# How do I get 5 records before AND after a record with a specific ID?

Tags: sql

I have a table named `scores` with the columns `id` and `score`. I want to access a specific record by its `id` as well as the 5 records before and after it. Is there a way in SQL to say "grab the score with the id of `n` and `x` items before and after it?"

Comment: are your ids numeric AND sequential?

Comment: yes ids are number and sequential - they are the primary key. i may be sorting by another field (like date_created) too. it's almost a sub-query in a way - something like, get me all the scores sorted by date_created desc, then given an id, get the 5 items before and after it.

Comment: SQL Server?  mysql?  Oracle?  Be specific and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I purposefully left it generic because I believed this functionality was core SQL functionality and DBMS agnostic. I use several DBMS' and didn't want a DBMS-specific answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM scores 
   WHERE score >= n
ORDER BY score ASC
   LIMIT 6

 UNION

  SELECT * 
    FROM scores 
   WHERE score < n
ORDER BY score DESC
   LIMIT 5
```

The syntax may vary somewhat depending upon what Database server you are using.

Comment: I think you may want `LIMIT 6` for the `>=` part of the union.

Comment: Thanks Justin - this is exactly what I was looking for. As a side note those select statements have to be wrapped in parens (at least for MySQL).